# Count the times that a String are repeated between two tables with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, count

Well I'm trying to get all the times that a String are repeated in two tables using a comun column and getting all the results with a While, like that:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hits") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) 
{
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(app) FROM info WHERE app='$row[page]'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) 

{

$toip = $row[0] ;  
}

echo '<td bgcolor="#75D169">'; 
    echo "$toip";
    echo '</td>';

    }
```

But it doesn't show it very well as you can see it here: http://ikillcraft.a0001.net/counter/view.php?pass=test

The output would be:

```
Instalaciones de                    4       0 
Instalaciones de IkillLauncher      3       3
Instalaciones de gogogoa            3       0 
Instalaciones de MasterShell        0       0
```

But I don't know how to do it. :(

Comment: You should be able to do this in a single piece of SQL. However assigning the results of both pieces of SQL to $result will cause a major problem with how your current SQL works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a single piece of SQL, something like this would do it:-

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.page, COUNT(b.app) AS AppCount
                        FROM hits a
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN info b
                        ON a.page = b.app
                        GROUP BY a.page";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) 
{
    echo '<td bgcolor="#75D169">'; 
    echo $row['AppCount'];
    echo '</td>';

}
```

Note I do not know your column names, and you should have all the non aggregate column names in the GROUP BY clause (ie, anything except the ones in the COUNT in this case)

Comment: I have the same error that yesterday: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: That suggests an error in the SQL. Quick double check and it looks OK, but to be more certain I would need to check it against your table definitions. Could you post those please?

Comment: You mean table definitions to its names? If it that's here are:
http://gyazo.com/5473c30c7b897848c2e26dedf167206a
http://gyazo.com/6f4078a4b779b226b1c56b5f4804dea9
I'm Spanish (I have only 14 years, and I don't know what you mean nicely) :/ Sorry. ;)

Comment: Ah, you have no id column. I have updated the answer to just use a.page

Comment: Oh lol, I have edited a thing that you have correct it before, (1 min ago) XD

Comment: THANKS! :) You +5 reputation. Ehm, one thing more, can you delete this part of your post: EDIT by Ikillnukes, I'm silly. xD
Wow, you are the best :P

Comment: Nothing there like that to edit. Think you managed to back out your edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your table structure, so I am doing guesswork here, but this should work:

```
SELECT hits.page, appgrouped.apphit
FROM (hits)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(app) as apphit, app
           FROM info 
           GROUP BY app) AS appgrouped ON appgrouped.app = hits.page
```

This would be quite slow - depending on how big:

```
SELECT COUNT(app) as apphit, app
FROM info 
GROUP BY app
```

This is, if it is big, then the above join will be very slow, and in that case, PHP code would be a better solution (yes it would be faster).